# How to obtain reference to a View Controller from UITabBarViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

EDIT: I was off base in my approach.  I'm trying to pass data from one VC to another.  The source VC is not controlled by a Tab Bar, so I can't reference the destination VC through it.  I am attempting to reference the destination VC thorough the Storyboard, but the data is still nil on the destination VC.  I'm using Core Data and wish to pass the ManagedObjectContext to another VC.  Here is the code:

```
......
                    do {
                        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        appUserID = user.userID!
                        } catch {
                        fatalError("Error: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
        self.passManagedObjectContext()
    }

    func passManagedObjectContext() {
        let profileTableViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileTableViewController
            profileTableViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
        }


I am passing data from the AppDelegate to other ViewControllers by referencing my TabBarViewControllers stack like so:



    let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        if let tabBarViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers {
            let profileNavController = tabBarViewControllers[4] as! UINavigationController
            let profileTableViewController = profileNavController.topViewController as! ProfileTableViewController
            profileTableViewController.managedObjectContext = context
        }
    }
.....
```

END EDIT
I'm trying to do the same now but from one ViewController to another that is accessed through the tab bar (no segue).  The code above does not recognize `window!.rootViewController` how can I reference the root `UITabBarController?`

Comment: You can share data accross view controllers of tabbar using segue

Comment: Where / when in AppDelegate are you trying to do this?

Comment: @DonMag I've passed data from the AppDelegate before and was attempting to use the same approach between VCs  They are not part of the same Navigation Stack and I can't do it through the Tab Bar, so I'm trying through the Storyboard.  Thanks.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon - You *might* be complicating things with window!, rootViewController, UITabBarController, pass data, etc, etc, etc... instead of thinking about what you're really trying to do. I suspect what you *want* to do is `access ManagedObjectContext from multiple viewcontrollers`? If so, try searching for *that* instead. You may find a much simpler and more flexible approach.

Comment: @DonMag.. Yeah.  On a Deadline and rushing it.  No shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` has a built-in optional property `tabBarController`, so inside your view controller you can access the `tabBarController` like so:

```
if let tabBarController = tabBarController {
    //get the controller you need from
    //tabBarController.viewControllers
    //and do whatever you need
}
```

Here is the current list of properties available in the 'Getting Other Related View Controllers' section of [Apple's UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#topics):

[image: UIViewController: 'Getting Other Related View Controllers']

Comment: I tried your approach, but only then realized the source VC is not part of the Tab Bars collection.  I'm trying to do it through the Storyboard.  Still no luck.  Have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than trying to pass the managed object context around on a view controller basis, have you tried accessing it from the AppDelegate from any view controller that needs it?